# android multipart image upload with json object

Tags: android, json, image, multipartform-data, slash

I want to upload images to server.

Here is the code,

```
  try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Constants.yigit);
        Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); // Setting up the encoding

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        StringBody jsonBody = new StringBody(getNewDemandRequestParams(), "application/json",null);
        FormBodyPart jsonBodyPart = new FormBodyPart("data", jsonBody);
        reqEntity.addPart(jsonBodyPart);

      if (getMainActivity().getImagesSavedData(0).size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < getMainActivity().getImagesSavedData(0).size(); i++) {
  File _file = new File(getMainActivity().getImagesSavedData(0).get(i).getFilePath());               
                FileBody _fileBody = new FileBody(_file, "image/jpg", "UTF-8");
 FormBodyPart fileBodyPart = new FormBodyPart(getMainActivity().getImagesSavedData(0).get(i).getImageName().replace(".jpg", ""), _fileBody);

                reqEntity.addPart(fileBodyPart);

                reqEntity.addPart(getMainActivity().getImagesSavedData(0).get(i).getImageName().replace(".jpg",""), _fileBody);



          }
        }

        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(reqEntity);
        Log.e("rsul", result);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();

        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

}
```

But the problem is jsonBodyPart is including slashes.

Request body like this:

> {"data"=>"{\"action\":\"YENITALEP\",\"app\":{\"version\":\"verisyon\"},\"data\":{\"invoices\":[{\"imageName\":\"1395914025134\",\"note\":\"\",\"type\":\"FATURA\",\"typeNo\":\"0\"}],\"note\":\"\",\"notification\":[{\"type\":\"BeniAray?n\",\"typeNo\":\"0\"}]},\"device\":{\"hardwareModel\":\"m7\",\"model\":\"HTC
>   One\",\"systemVersion\":\"4.4.2\",\"uid\":\"00000000-7f39-faab-b500-7f280e9b4fed\"},\"timestamp\":\"Date(1391073711000+0200)\"}",
>   "1395914025134"=>#,
>   @original_filename="1395914025134.jpg", @content_type="image/jpg;
>   charset=UTF-8", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"1395914025134\";
>   filename=\"1395914025134.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg;
>   charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n">}

How can  I post a complex json object and images using multipart? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

check once this code iam using this one for uploading images to server

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity();
for(int i=0;i<allimagespath.size();i++){
Bitmap bm = ShrinkBitmap(allimagespath.get(i), 140, 140);
String format = allimagespath.get(i).substring((allimagespath.get(i).lastIndexOf(".")+1) ,  allimagespath.get(i).length());
Bitmap bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 140, 140, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 if(format.equalsIgnoreCase("png")){
    bit.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100 , blob);
 }else{
    bit.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , blob);
 }
bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
ByteArrayBody thumbbmp = new ByteArrayBody(bitmapdata, "thumb."+format);
FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(new File(allimagespath.get(i)));               
multipartContent.addPart("uploaded_file["+i+"]", bin2);
multipartContent.addPart("uploaded_thumb["+i+"]", thumbbmp);
}
multipartContent.addPart("count", new StringBody(""+allimagespath.size()));
postRequest.setEntity(multipartContent);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```